# Getting ambiguity error in location column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run the below query , I am getting **ambiguity error in location column** . Can anyone please explain what is the logical error here

```
select firstname,lastname,location,total_count,avg_sal 
from employee join 
(
    select location,count(location),avg(salary) 
    from employee 
    group by location
) temp_table on employee.location=temp_table.location;
```

Comment: Please publish the error message in full.

Comment: It's good programming practice to _qualify_ all columns, especially when several tables are involved. E.g. `employee.location` instead of just `location`.

Answer (score 1):

try putting employee.location in the select. Both your tables have a column called location and so the select statement doesn't know which tables column called location you want.

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, employee.location, total_count,avg_sal 
from employee 
join ( 
    select location, count(location), avg(salary) 
    from employee 
    group by location
) temp_table on employee.location = temp_table.location;
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your issue is that the optimizer does not know from which table (`employee` or the derived `temp_table`) each colums refers, plus you are also missing the aliases in the derived table referred in the outer query - using *aliases* elimiates ambiguity, try:

```
select e.firstname, e.lastname, e.location, t.total_count, t.avg_sal 
from employee e
join (
  select location, count(location) total_count, avg(salary) avg_sal
    from employee 
    group by location
) t
on e.location = t.location;
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the main `employee` table and the inner `temp_table` have a `location` field. You need to clarify which one you want in the select list.

I know it seems like it shouldn't matter, since they the fields are guaranteed to have the same value.

```
on employee.location = temp_table.location;
```

They even source from the same base table. ***But that's not the whole story.***

To understand why, say you have a pair of rows like this:

| firstname | lastname | location | salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jane | Doe | new york | 54 |
| John | Smith | New York | 50 |

The location in both of those fields is the same for purposes of the `GROUP BY` and `ON` conditional expressions, but for one of those rows the grouped (temp_table) location value will be **different** for purposes of the `SELECT` list.

Which one should you show? The database can't just assume either way which one you mean. You have to be explicit by prefacing the column with a table name or alias.